# Using a content from a ZeroMQ-stream for a webpage

Tags: python, zeromq

I have this code in Python.

With this I can output the content of the ZeroMQ-stream to a file. Only writing to a file every 10 seconds does not seem to be really useful and costs a lot of performance.

Now I would like to show the content in a web-page. I've seen `PyBottle` exist, which in Python creates a web server.

How can I integrate `PyBottle` in my code, so it can output the latest message of the stream? I thought about the code of `PyBottle` in the **`while`**-loop.

But do not I ( unnecessarily ) create a new web-server instance?

How can I handle this?

---

Sample of `PyBottle`:

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route( '/hello/<name>' )
def index( name ):
    return template( '<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name = name )

run( host = 'localhost', port = 8080 )
```

---

My Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from gzip       import GzipFile
from cStringIO  import StringIO
from subprocess import call
pass;           import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

subscriber = context.socket( zmq.XSUB )
subscriber.connect( "tcp://pubsub.*******.nl:7664" )
subscriber.send( chr( 0x01 )             # { 0x01: ZMQ_XSUB.subscribe,
               + "/RIG/VehiclePositions" #   0x00: ZMQ_XSUB.unsubscribe
                 )                       #   }
while   True:

        multipart =  subscriber.recv_multipart()
        address   =  multipart[0]
        contents  = ''.join(multipart[1:])
        contents  =  GzipFile( '', 'r', 0, StringIO( contents ) ).read()
        filename  = "tmp/treinpos.txt"
        file      =  open( filename, "w" )
        file.write( contents )
        file.close()

subscriber.close()
context.term()
```

Comment: Anyone  who has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

### Generating repetitive costs is a sign of a bad design practice:

Right,
rather extend the `PyBottle`, or whatever other web-serving framework to instantiate rather just once ( may use load-balancing workers later, for further increasing the architecture's performance envelope ), where it also creates its own ZeroMQ **`Context()`**-IO-datapump engine. This enables the web-serving methods communicate with the rest of the content-generating agents and pre-construct the actual dynamic content both a-priori, ad-hoc and also on-the-fly.

The rest of your architecture will become smarter and way more light-weight, as all your interactions become signalling/messaging-based, avoiding fileIO-tortures of a filesystem at all.

### Additional ZeroMQ performance tricks available

- may fine-tune via `.setsockopt()` the remote-terminal I/O-costs + performance by **`zmq.CONFLATE`**, **`zmq.IMMEDIATE`** and other ISO/OSI-L3-layer parameters
- may harden the web-serving code by connectivity white-listing + size-ceilings

and many further performance trick to squeeze maximum performance even from restricted code-execution environment inside the real-world **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)** ecosystem.

Comment: And what is your idea then?

Comment: No idea for a solution for this beginner??